# ubuntu 14.04.3 bootloader cannot be installed at specified location

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

[retina 15" Macbook Pro 2014, rEFInd, OS X, & Ubuntu 14.04.3]

Installing Ubuntu, I've chosen the 'Other' option from the template menu.  My partitions are setup as follows:

```
/dev/sda
  free space            0MB
  /dev/sda1    efi      209MB
  /dev/sda2    hfs+     299999MB
  /dev/sda3    hfs+     650MB
  free space            0MB
  /dev/sda4    ext4  /  183031MB
  free space            0MB
  /dev/sda5    swap     16384MB
  free space            2MB
```

When I click `Install Now`, I get a message box stating that I need to setup a separate partition for boot loader code and that the partition should be marked as `Reserved BIOS boot area`.  So I setup the last free space (2MB) as `Reserved BIOS boot area` and it became /dev/sda6.

For the `Device for boot loader installation` option, I specify /dev/sda6 andcontinue with `Install Now` and the installation progresses.  When the installation is about to finish, I'm getting an error message stating:

```
Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda6' failed.
This is a fatal error.
<OK>
```

Then, as per the title of this post, I get a message box that states that the boot loader cannot be installed at the specified location and I have three options:

1) Choose a different device
2) Continue without a bootloader
3) Cancel the installation

I've tried selecting another partition (/dev/sda4) but get the same error and I don't want to specify /dev/sda1-/dev/sda3 as they are hfs+ partitions and I don't want to corrupt my OS X install.

I've read the other questions here on the topic but they don't seem to apply to my case, the given answers explain the differences between BIOS and EFI and MBR and GPT, and neither have an accepted answer from the person who posted.

I don't understand why the Installer is forcing me to specify a `Reserved BIOS boot area` partition, then complains that it can't use it.

Any advice on what I should change about the way I've setup my partitions would be most welcome.

Comment: A bios_grub partition of 1 or 2MB is required for BIOS boot when you have gpt partitioned drive. But you really want UEFI boot which will use the existing ESP - efi system partition. So boot Ubuntu install media in UEFI mode not BIOS boot mode.

Comment: How do I do that?  When my Mac starts up and the CD is loaded, I have 3 extra icons to choose from; `EFI\boot\grubx64.efi from 2MiB FAT volume`, `Fallback boot loader from 2 MiB FAT volume`, and `Legacy OS from whole disk volume` .   I've been picking the last one.
Surprisingly, I've actually got it working finally by simply choosing the replace existing install option from the template menu.  Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

The message about the "reserved BIOS boot area" (what the rest of the world calls a [BIOS Boot Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_Boot_partition)) indicates that your installer has booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. You might do better with an EFI-mode installation, although there's another way around this issue (see below). First, though, I strongly advise you to exercise caution. Installing a BIOS-mode boot loader to a partition that should not hold it can render all data on the partition inaccessible. If you're lucky, you might be able to recover files with advanced data-recovery tools, but you'll waste a lot of time (your own and others') because of a moment's impatience.

In an EFI-mode installation, the boot loader is stored as ordinary files in the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which in your case is `/dev/sda1`. The Ubuntu installer doesn't actually ask where to install GRUB on such systems; it's smart enough to identify the ESP and install GRUB there. If you partition manually, though, the ESP must be appropriately flagged (as an "EFI boot partition" on older versions or as an ESP on newer versions). This should happen automatically, but you should not change that identification. Note that this will happen only if you boot the Ubuntu installer in EFI mode, which you apparently have not done. (The installer sets up a BIOS-mode boot loader if it's booted in BIOS mode and an EFI-mode boot loader if it's booted in EFI mode.)

Finally, to the other way around the issue: You said you're using my rEFInd boot manager. rEFInd doesn't need GRUB -- BIOS-mode or EFI-mode. If you've already installed rEFInd in OS X, and if your Ubuntu installation has completed *except* for the GRUB installation, you can boot to OS X and install an EFI filesystem driver for ext4fs. See the [rEFInd driver documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html) and the [rEFInd page on booting Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/linux.html) for lots more details. The `mountesp` script, which comes with rEFInd, should mount your ESP, enabling you to copy the ext4fs driver, which also comes with rEFInd, to the right location. Alternatively, you can re-run the `refind-install` script. This is overkill, but the script should detect that Ubuntu is now installed and set up the ext4fs driver automatically. Yet a third option is to use rEFInd on a CD-R or USB flash drive to boot to Ubuntu, then re-install rEFInd via the Debian package or PPA. In any event, once the ext4fs driver is installed, rEFInd should detect your Linux kernels and enable you to boot.